# Trouble understanding the unique_lock

Tags: c++

I have some trouble understanding the unique_lock and condition_variable in the code below.

```
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std;

mutex m;
int i=1;
condition_variable cv;

void funcA()
{
    cout << "FuncA Before lock" << endl;
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
    cout << "FuncA After lock" << endl;

    while(i != 2) { cv.wait(lk); }

    //std::chrono::milliseconds dura(500);//make sure thread is running
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);        //this_thread::sleep_for(dura);
    cout << "FuncA After sleep" << endl;
    lk.unlock();
    cv.notify_all();
}

void funcB()
{
    cout << "FuncB Before lock" << endl;
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
    cout << "FuncB After lock" << endl;
    
    while(i != 1) { cv.wait(lk); }

    //std::chrono::milliseconds dura(500);//make sure thread is running
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);        //this_thread::sleep_for(dura);
    cout << "FuncB After sleep" << endl;

    ++i;
    lk.unlock();
    cv.notify_all();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto a = thread(funcA), b=thread(funcB);
    a.join(), b.join();
    return 0;
}
```

As per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock (when the constructor is called with a mutex) the constructor locks the associated mutex by calling `m.lock()`

Let us say, threadA/funcA gets scheduled first by the operating system. So, the following lines will get executed

```
    cout << "FuncA Before lock" << endl;
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
    cout << "FuncA After lock" << endl;
    while(i != 2) { cv.wait(lk); }
```

Now, threadA has the mutex since the constructor for the unique_lock has called lock on  it. However, since `i!=2`, the thread will stay in the while-loop waiting to be notified by the other thread.

Now, let us say the operating system switches the threads and funcB is called.

```
    cout << "FuncB Before lock" << endl;
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
```

Now, this thread should get stuck here on the second line right? Because mutex `m` is already owned by threadA (since it has called `m.lock()` on it), and therefore the `m.lock()` call by `unique_lock` constructor should block since the mutex is not available.

So, there's a deadlock? The threadA is waiting in the infinite loop waiting for `i` to be incremented to `2`, whereas threadB is waiting for the mutex owned by threadA.

However, nothing like that happens, and the code works fine.

Comment: Read what `wait` does with the passed in mutex: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait

Comment: Ahh, got it. `Atomically unlocks lock`. that's the key. Thanks!